# How to describe the failure of this linear modelling?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, residuals

I have a time series $X_t$, which is shown in the first plot. In the second plot, I am doing a linear regression on $X_t\sim X_{t-1}$. The regression line is very close to $y=x$. But this is tricky since if if we look at the bottom left or the top right part of the data, they are almost random. From the diagnosis of residuals, it is not a good regression either. But the model passes all the $t$ tests and $F$ tests. How can I say it's not a good model then? Is there a statistic  to describe (not visually) the failure of this modelling?

Here are the `R` codes I used to generate the plots:

```
# Generating X_t
x=c(arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0),ar=0.1),n=64,sd=1),3,5,7,11,14,17,rep(20,64)+arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0),ar=0.1),n=64,sd=1))
# Regression X_t~X_{t-1}
reg=lm(x[2:length(x)]~x[1:(length(x)-1)])
# Plotting
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(x,xlab='',ylab=expression(X[t]),ty='l')
plot(x[1:(length(x)-1)],x[2:length(x)],xlab=expression(x[t-1]),ylab=expression(x[t]) ,main=paste('coeff= ',round(reg$coefficients[2],2)))
# Plotting the regression line
abline(reg,col=2)
# Plotting the residual diagnose
plot(reg)
```

[image]

Comment: What leads you to believe that the regression has "failed"?

Comment: @JakeWestfall  Thanks for your comment. From the Residuals VS Fitted values plot. I suppose it should be randomly around 0. Besides, the bottom-left and the top-right part of the data are randomly distributed if you look at them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regression does what you ask, and quite well in regression terms. The real question to me is why you think it interesting or useful.

You simulated a time series which is one regime with small fluctuations followed by another regime with small fluctuations, with a short transition between the two. More precisely, if I decipher your code correctly, it is one autoregressive scheme with mean 0 followed by another with mean 20 with a steep ramp in between. (As like myself many people here don't use R routinely, a verbal explanation would have been helpful.)

That being so, $x_t \approx x_{t-1}$ is a good overall approximation and that's essentially what your regression reports. But you've discovered, indirectly, what you invented in the first place.

Otherwise put, it is inevitable that your data are two big blobs plus transitional values, so a straight line is a fair descriptor, but that just follows from the simulation rule.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the problems and agree with  your answer.

Comment: This question  actually origins from [the other one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77838/how-to-distinguish-these-two-linear-regressions/77840?noredirect=1#77840) which you also gave some useful comments on.  I am studying this because I wanted to distinguish this regression and the other (more normal) type of regression.

Comment: I commented on that question earlier, but I hadn't seen the connection. This underlines that you need to make links for us!

Comment: I thought the residuals of the two regressions behaved differently from each other, which I could use for distinguishing. But now I realised that's not true. Both of them are fitted well. Thanks again for your answer.